# If Vanellope decided to remain a glitch, why could she leave the game in "Wreck-It Ralph 2"?

Tags: wreck-it-ralph, ralph-breaks-the-internet

At the end of *Wreck-It Ralph*, President Vanellope decides not to give up her "glitch" powers - she says something along the lines of "Why would I want to give that up?", and demonstrates that she can still "glitch" from place to place, calling it a superpower.

Earlier, we saw that since she was a glitch, she can't leave the game - there's an effect similar to a force field that blocks her. Given that she still has her glitch abilities, how is she able to leave to the Internet in *Ralph Breaks the Internet*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having the ability to glitch and being a glitch isn't the same thing.

When Ralph confronts Sour Bill about Vanellope's picture being on the side of the game the following conversation takes place

> Sour Bill: Vanellope was a racer until King Candy tried to delete her code!
>
> Ralph: Tried to delete her code? So that's why she's a glitch!

After Sour Bill explains that King Candy also locked up all of their memories he says:

> He'll do anything to keep her from racing. Because if she crosses the finish line, the game will reset and she won't be a glitch anymore!

Vanellope did cross the finish line and her code was reconnected to the rest of the game making her no longer a glitch. However, she chose to keep the **ability to glitch out.**  She did not decide to **remain a glitch.** Thus she can leave her game whenever she wishes.

Comment: I think that the implication was that her special ability was the glitch-looking flash teleport.. I don't remember anything suggesting she chose, or otherwise had the ability to choose to keep something like this.